# Android Wear notifications on a non-wearable device

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, notifications, wear-os

Is it possible to use Android Wear notifications on a device other than a wearable, or is it possible to emulate a wearable device on a phone?

**Update:**
As seen in **[this link](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/install-the-android-wear-launcher-on-your-android-device/)** the wear launcher emulator was extracted, and converted to an .apk file enabling the wear experience on a phone.

Now, let's say I want to write a phone launcher compatible with wear notifications, where is a good place to start?